# Unit Testing with a Mocked Class

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Some sites I have looked at state that while you (the developer) are implementing your class (X) which depends on another class (Y) for information and assume that class (Y) has not yet been developed by your development team, then in your unit testing of class (X) you should mock class (Y).

What I want to know is what you should do when eventually class (Y) does get implemented by the development team? Does the developer of class (X) now have to go back to the unit tests where he/she created mocks of class (Y) and call the real object instead?

And if we were to put real development timelines into perspective class (X) may have been implemented a month or more before class (Y) and the developer of class (X) who has also written the unit tests for class (X) probably has moved on to other tasks assigned to him/her; how could this person now allocate time to go back and re-invest the time to rewrite their old unit tests - wouldn't this just be a management nightmare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I would say that you achieve better separation and independence in your tests if you simply leave the mocks in--you can have true unit tests in this way, while if you were to replace the mocks with instances of the actual classes then you are creating integration tests. It's two schools of thought really, [mockist vs. classical](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#ClassicalAndMockistTesting). Personally, I prefer the mockist style and am comfortable knowing that my tests are more resilient to change because I write them this way. If I did more of the classical style testing, there would be more reasons for test failure (could be a change in any of the underlying implementations that my test subject depends on the behavior of) and when there is a test failure, it is less clear about exactly what is causing the failure.

Comment: You do however want to do continuous integration tests anyway so as to have the shortest fallback path to a stable functionality. So would you than not be doubling the testing effort one as writing the tests against a mock object and then re-writing the tests against the real object? I do not oppose your idea about having a true unit test being against a mocked dependency but I am trying to find a way to achieve the same testing results with much less effort in the long run - perhaps because I consider myself lazy :)

Comment: Integration Tests / Acceptance Tests will eventually use the real objects however, they don't have to so thoroughly test every path. Also the other developers of Object Y should have their own tests to verify that they correctly implement the interface.

Comment: @Tikky, personally, I like to work in the Test-Driven Development style where I am writing tests before the code that makes them pass. It's a skill that can take a while to develop, especially if you have been used to working without tests or by developing tests after your production code, but it's very worth the effort in my view. As a developer, I prefer if someone else worries about the integration tests, but sometimes I do need to write those also--again my goal will be to keep the required components to a minimum. I am well satisfied with such a collection of tests for my purposes.